# Worker processes in node.js aren't writing files

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I utilise clusters to defer workloads in my application, and one task a worker may have to do is write a file. However I'm having some trouble getting worker threads to write to files. Here are the test cases I used:

This will work just fine:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');

var filepath = path.join(__dirname, "image.jpg");
request({url:"http://i.imgur.com/InnEHyN.jpg"}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

var filepath2 = path.join(__dirname, "test.txt");
fs.writeFile(filepath2, "Sample Text");
```

However, when i try to do these operations from a worker thread, they do not occur. I dont get any errors or output from the console, it just seems to silently fail.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var cluster = require('cluster');

if(cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.fork();
}else {
  var filepath = path.join(__dirname, "image.jpg");
  request({url:"http://i.imgur.com/InnEHyN.jpg"}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

  var filepath2 = path.join(__dirname, "test.txt");
  fs.writeFile(filepath2, "Sample Text");
}
```

additionally, if I use the library `fs-extra` found [here](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) I can call `fse.ensureFileSync(filepath)` and the file will be created. However, even with an empty file there, I can not seem to write to it by either piping, or using the `fs.writeFile` function.